# Choosing cameras for stereo vision system?

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

I'm in the process of building a stereo vision system with YOLO detection. The system have to detect airplanes in far distance and also measure the depth from the airplane to the camera. I think because of the long distance that I have from the camera to the airplane, I must have cameras with a high resolution, maybe also a big baseline. I should use a wide-angle lens with shor focal lenth that can improve the YOLO object detection. I understand that I have to be very carefuly with the camera calibration. What are the best practices for picking cameras for that stereo vision system?